# apt-get auto prompt disappears after kernel upgrade

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, kernel, vps

I've got some problem about bash.

Before today, my VPS (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) was using kernel 2.x. (Because it was upgraded from 11.04 and the boot options did not get updated.)

Today I want to use kernel 3.2 as the default kernel.

After modifying the grub config, I've successfully booted the VPS up in kernel 3.2. Using `uname -r` will show `3.2.0-24-generic` instead of `2.x.y-z-generic` now.

However, something wonky happened and I don't why.

Before the kernel change, if I type some unkown command, the shell will prompt me to use apt-get to install it. For example, I don't have `bind9` installed, and when I try to run `named`, I will be prompted like this:

```
wzyboy@vermilion:~$ named
The program 'named' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install bind9
```

Sometimes when I make a typo, I will be corrected ("did you mean"):

```
wzyboy@vermilion:~$ namedd
No command 'namedd' found, did you mean:
 Command 'named' from package 'bind9' (main)
namedd: command not found
```

However, after the kernel change, when I try to run `named`, the shell simply says:

```
wzyboy@natatio:/$ named
-bash: named: command not found
```

I think it may be something wrong with bash, but I don't know how to fix the problem. Can anybody help?

[SOLVED] Thanks! After installing `command-not-found` package, the problem is solved. However, I still don't why the package got lost after changing the kernel...

Comment: chances are that you did more things than simply installing the new kernel. you could check /var/log/apt/history.log, /var/log/aptitude and/or var/log/dpkg.log to see what happened. maybe you uninstalled a package that depended on "command-not-found" and the latter was removed since it was only installed to satisfy that dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable those auto suggestions you need to ensure that you have *command-not-found* installed. It is usually automatically enabled via */etc/bash.bashrc* if installed correctly.